# How do u clean an hp laptop keyboard from nail polish remover

Tags: organic-chemistry

I was cleaning my nails with nail polish remover(isopropyl acetone, methyl ethyl ketone, and n-methyl-pyrrolidone) and I touched my computer and I saw a white stain so I tried to take it off with all-purpose cleaner but that did not work so I look at my computer and I see the whiteness so how can I remove it.

Comment: You do not - laptop isn't a nail.

Comment: @Mithoron. How could Amineh Elhoodary have discovered that the same question was asked 5 yers ago ?

Comment: @Maurice https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=nail+polish+remover

Answer (score 1):

It is not just a stain that could be cleaned off by dissolving or fine brushing by a wipe. The plastic is already damaged.

I see only few ways, none really good :

- Colour the spots by some colour ( markers ? ) to be as least disturbing as possible.
- Peel off the damaged spots to the undamaged layers, but the original surface texture would be lost, so the result may not be better..
- If it is a free, not functional surface, put there some decoration stick label.